# Display taxonomy term description within the content page

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms

I've a content type with some fields, one of the field is associated with a taxonomy and it has some terms (each term has its own description). Here, when I input the field with the terms and submit the content. The content page appears as:

```
[title] : title of the content.

[field1] : 

[field2] :

[taxonomy] : [term1]

             [term2]

             [term3]
```

The content page is viewed with all the fields and taxonomy terms with an anchor/link. I would also like to include the description in its display as

```
[term1] : [description]

[term2] : [description]

[term3] : [description]
```

Any Ideas on how to get this done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the display suite module. Install and enable the ds module. Then you will have a new 'Rendered taxonomy term' formatter. Go to the 'manage display' option for the content type you created. Just select the 'Rendered Taxonomy Term' for the format for your taxonomy field and you will get the description displayed.

Comment: There is no 'Rendered Taxonomy term' option in the format. There are only 4 options 1. link, 2. Plain Text, 3. RSS Category, 4. hidden.

Comment: Sorry didn't realise that 'Rendered Taxonomy Term' came from the display suite module. Have updated the answer to include that information.